# ZSH completion order

Tags: shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I have a ZSH completer that provides the expected completions, but provides them in lexicographical order, as opposed to the order in which they were added via `compadd`:

```
_matcher_complete() {
  (git ls-files 2>/dev/null || find .) | /usr/local/bin/matcher -l20 ${words[CURRENT]} | while read line; do
    compadd -U "$line"
  done
  compstate[insert]=menu
}

zle -C matcher-complete complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:matcher-complete:*' completer _matcher_complete
zstyle ':completion:matcher-complete:*' menu-select

bindkey '^X^T' matcher-complete
```

How can I order the completions by insertion order?

Answer (score 2):

Using another ZSH completion script for inspiration, I changed the `_matcher_complete` function to the following:

```
_matcher_complete() {
  integer i=1
  (git ls-files 2>/dev/null || find .) | /usr/local/bin/matcher --limit 20 ${words[CURRENT]} | while read line; do
    compadd -U -2 -V $i -- "$line"
    i=$((i+1))
  done
  compstate[insert]=menu
}
```

Note the different args to `compadd`. I haven't had enough time to actually grok what each flag is doing (see [man zshcompwid](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompwid)), but it appears you need to specify the order explicitly (thus the use of `$i` in the function above).

Assuming you have [`matcher`](https://github.com/burke/matcher) installed, this code will give you fuzzy path completion ala [`Command-T`](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T)/[`CtrlP`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim).